# Playing music from iPod

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ipod

How can I play music from my iPod using my laptop with ubuntu 10.10 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hook it up and play the music files on the device.

Answer (score 0):

Use one of the many audio players included with Ubuntu. Amarok for example is good for syncing your iPod with your computer.